# Comparing string object dates in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using `XmlPullParser` to fetch and parse an RSS feed and store entries in a database.  I'm storing the date as a `String` object in a format of "Dec 15, 2020" for example.

While I'm parsing the RSS feed I want to do a comparison to set a flag if the entry is before/after the data "Jan 1, 2021."

What would be the best way to do this?  Is there a way to do it as strings or am I better off using `Date` objects?

Answer (score 1):

You would parse the string as a `LocalDate` (because it seems that you are only comparing dates without timezone information) using the `DateTimeFormatter` from the modern Java/Kotlin time API in the `java.time.*` package.

In your case, since you want to parse a specific pattern, you would use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern: String)` to create the formatter. The whole class docs are available [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter)

Then you would compare the parsed `LocalDate` to another `LocalDate` of your choice with `.isBefore(other)` or `.isAfter(other)` calls.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.Month
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

// ...

val rssDate = "Dec 15, 2020"

// your pattern
val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy")

val inputDate = LocalDate.parse(rssDate, dateFormatter)

val targetDate = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.JANUARY, 1)
if (inputDate.isBefore(targetDate)) {
    // before
} else {
    // after
}
```

Comparing date strings as strings, or otherwise dealing with dates (or time in general) without using a good time API will only lead to bugs. Also using the outdated older Java time APIs will eventually lead to bugs. Use the modern `java.time.*` API and beware of [falsehoods we believe about time](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca).

If you have to support older Android API levels (lower than 26) you need Android Gradle plugin of at least v4.0.0+ for the `java.time.*`  APIs to be available (support for core library desugaring).